# Pointer to QMainWindow Changing

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance

I am using Qt to create a window and I have the following code (this is somewhat in pseudo-code):

```
class MyInterface {
    virtual void doupdate() = 0;
}

class InterfaceHandler {
    InterfaceHandler(MyInterface *i) {
      the_int = i;

      start_thread(&mainloop);
    }

    void mainloop() {
        while(1) the_int->doupdate();
    }

    MyInterface *the_int;
}

class console : public QMainWindow, public MyInterface {
    console() {
            InterfaceHandler x(this);
    }

    void doupdate() {
        //code to modify the gui
    }
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    console w(argc, argv);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

My issue is that when `the_int->doupdate()` is called in `mainloop()`, the reference to `the_int` is wrong.  I think this has to do with the fact that `console` inherits `QMainWindow`, but I am not sure what the solution is.

`MyInterface` doesn't always get inherited by a `QObject`.  I've tried to split the `doupdate()` from `console` into another class which gets passed the reference to `console` in the constructor, but get the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: `the_int` should be called `the_iface` or something because in a C++ question we'd generally assume `the_int` was an integer. But anyway...does this only happen in interaction with the threading (e.g. can `doupdate()` be called in the InterfaceHandler constructor fine, but goes bad later?)

Comment: How do you allocate a console object? It's not on the stack is it?

Comment: `the_int` is just in this example.  Yes, this seems to be an issue with threading.  When I call it in the constructor, I have no issues.  I print out the location of the pointer after I create it (in the constructor) and then again when I am calling `mainloop()`, but they are different.  My allocation of `console` has been added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "pseudo-code" is close enough to your real code, the following is the problem:

```
console() {
  InterfaceHandler x(this);
}
```

Once the constructor is done, `x`, being a local (automatic) variable, gets destroyed. The `InterfaceHandler` instance you created no longer exists once the constructor returns.

You need to keep `x` as a member variable of that class, or create and store it from somewhere else. (But keeping it as a member makes sense since the lifetimes of the objects are tied.) You also need to be very careful with that thread, it needs to be stopped before `console` is destroyed.

Comment: don't you hate it when you think you have tried something already and it didn't work.  that's what happened here.  thanks for having me try it again.